# How do I pacify the Moth Priest in Dawnguard?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I accidentally attacked the moth priest in Dawnguard. How do I settle him down? I've got it on PS3.

Comment: Are you on console or PC?  If you are on PC, you can use the command console to pacify him.

Comment: @zero298 whether OP is on PC or not is irrelevant, post the command as an answer so future visitors may benefit.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on PC, you can use the command console.

1. Press `` ` `` (Backtick, not single quote)
2. Click on the NPC you want to pacify
3. Type `setav aggression 0`

Hopefully he will not be aggressive towards you anymore.

Full list of commands you can use can be found here: [Skyrim:Console](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console)

Specifically, you are using the `setav` meaning "Set Actor Value" and you are then setting the value of `aggression` to `0`  The full list of Actor Values can be found here: [Tes5Mod:Actor Value Indices](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes5Mod:Actor_Value_Indices)

If you are on console, you can try getting away from the NPC and then sleeping or resting or waiting for several in game days and hopefully he will no longer be aggressive.